# Best way to convert or load External files in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, payu

I have Started Payment Gateway Integration of Pay U biz in Codeigniter Framework. 
I downloaded the PHP SDK from Here : https://developer.payubiz.in/documentation/Platform-based/29

Now, I tested it and it's working just fine without a framework, but i have to integrate it with **Code igniter Framework**.

I tried with this Example :
Note : **payu.php** is the main file which is downloaded from it's website.

```
<?php

require_once dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/payu.php';

/* Payments made easy. */

pay_page( array (   'key' => 'gtKFFx', 'txnid' => uniqid( 'animesh_' ), 'amount' => rand( 0, 100 ),
            'firstname' => 'Test', 'email' => 'test@payu.in', 'phone' => '1234567890',
            'productinfo' => 'Product Info', 'surl' => 'payment_success', 'furl' => 'payment_failure'), 'eCwWELxi' );

/* And we are done. */



function payment_success() {
    /* Payment success logic goes here. */
    echo "Payment Success" . "<pre>" . print_r( $_POST, true ) . "</pre>";
}

function payment_failure() {
    /* Payment failure logic goes here. */
    echo "Payment Failure" . "<pre>" . print_r( $_POST, true ) . "</pre>";
}
```

It's working fine without a framework. But i want to convert it in codeigniter so how can i convert it to codeigniter.

I tried with making library of **payu.php** file. and autoloading that library but it's not working so how can i convert it in codeigniter? What is the best option of converting it into codeigniter?

> So not for only this payment gateway Integration if we want to use
>   another sdk or any thing else like pay u biz. what is the best way to convert or load
>   external files in code igniter Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use require_once

```
require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/ion_auth.php');
```

Codeigniter is has this APPPATH which points to your applications folder. Then you can point to any folder from there. Hope this works

**Goodluck meyt**

Comment: oh  thank you so..much . just that much simple.. I was not aware of it . it's working absolutely fine :)

Comment: I'm happy to help!! Happy coding! :)